# Compare two column in two different files using awk

Tags: awk

I have two files as given below

## file1

```
1|a
2|b
3|c
4|d
5|e
6|g
7|h
8|i
```

## file2

```
2
3
```

## expected output using awk in linux

```
1|a
4|d
5|e
6|g
7|h
8|i
```

Tried below but not getting expected op

```
awk '{k=$1 FS $2} NR!=FNR{a[k]; next} !(k in a)' file1 file2
```

## expected output using awk in linux

```
1|a
4|d
5|e
6|g
7|h
8|i
```

Comment: you need to print lines from file1 whose line number are not in file2?

Comment: Could you please do let me know if this solution has helped you?

Answer (score 2):

We have to set different `FS` for both Input_file(s) since once Input_file is PIPE(`|`) delimited and other is not, could you please try following. This will only print those lines which are NOT in Input_file2 and present in Input_file1.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$0];next} !($1 in a)'  Input_file2  FS="|"  Input_file1
```

Output will be as follows.

```
1|a
4|d
5|e
6|g
7|h
8|i
```

---

---

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation for above command.

```
awk '                                       ##Starting awk program from here.
FNR==NR{                                    ##Checking condition FNR==NR which will be TRUE when Input_file2 is being read.
  a[$0]                                     ##Creating an array named a whose index is $0 here.
  next                                      ##next function is awk out of the box function which skips all further statements from here onward.
}                                           ##Closing BLOCK for FNR==NR condition here.
!($1 in a)                                  ##Checking condition if $1 is NOT present in Input_file1, this condition will be executed when Input_file named Input_file1 is being read.
'  Input_file2  FS="|"  Input_file1         ##Mentioning Input_file2 name then setting FS as pipe and mentioning Input_file1 here.
```